# typescript static method lead to SyntaxError in PhantomJs

Tags: javascript, typescript, static, phantomjs, static-methods

in `PantomJS` I'm testing a Typescript class like:

```
class Test {
  static foo(){
    return 'bar'
  }
}
```

which is compiled to JS into:

```
var Test = (function () {
    function Test() {
    }
    Test.foo = function () {
        return 'bar';
    };
    return Test;
}());
```

but it throws:

`SyntaxError: Functions cannot be declared in a nested block in strict mode`

While work perfectly if tested in `Chrome`.

Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: Sounds like the version of PhantomJS you're using doesn't understand ES2015 classes. Solution would be to upgrade to something that does, transpile before it sees them, or not use them.

Comment: what is "target" option value in your `tsc` configuration? It's import to understand how it's compiled to JS

Comment: @T.J.Crowder code is transpiled to JS before being tested,
@Maximus `"target": "es5"`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I guess not necessarily, it's of `any` type be default

Comment: @teone, the error says in `strict mode`, where is your `use strict;` statement?

Comment: There's no strict mode violation in that transpiled code at all. If PhantomJS thinks there is, it's mistaken. I suspect it's being asked to read the wrong file or similar.

Comment: @Maximus: Thanks. I forgot that you're allowed to leave that off.

Comment: Yes, it's not entire code. Please add all the code used in production

Comment: Mmm... starting to consider that the reported is not the issue, I thought it was since it was the last change before everything broke, full code is here: https://gerrit.opencord.org/#/c/1903/